# Changing from 2x5 columns to 1x10 on larger screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I guess the solution to this problem is pretty simple, and yet I'm struggling. I have 10 icons which i want centered on middle and displayed in one row on large screens, and then changed to two rows of 5 icons each on smaller screens. How should I code this using bootstrap?

```
<div class="row">
          <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/1_g.png"></div>
          <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/2_g.png"></div>
          <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/3_g.png"></div>
          <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/4_g.png"></div>
          <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/5_g.png"></div>
          <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/6_g.png"></div>
          <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/7_g.png"></div>
          <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/8_g.png"></div>
          <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/9_g.png"></div>
          <div class="col"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/10_g.png"></div>
        </div>
```

The way it acts now is resizing regularly, for instance on certain widths is it displayed as 1x7,1x3. I want it to only have two options: 1x10 or 2x5.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code so far in the question, otherwise this risks being closed as too broad (and implementations will vary wildly based on your markup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bootstrap, you can add these classes:

- Extra small (<576px): .col
- Small (≥576px): .col-sm-
- Medium (≥768px): .col-md-
- Large (≥992px): .col-lg-
- Extra large (≥1200px): .col-xl-

So for your case, you can do something like :

```html
<div class="col col-lg-2"><img class="img-fluid cat_icon" src="img/Icons/1_g.png"></div>
```